# Angular and NGX-Masonry - display issue

Tags: angular, angular-material, masonry

I wanted to integrate Masonry into an Angular application.
I installed the [ngx-masonry library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-masonry).
The problem: When rendered, my page has a huge gap between the headline and the masonry-content.
My expected behavior: Every card should start at the very top.

[Screenshot with percentage width like it should be at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nBYa.png)
(The first card is the grey box starting at the bottom)

Below that gap, the cards align as expected.

This is the code in my html file (simplified, in reality i have one item in width2 and 7 in the "normal" width. I hoped that this will suffice)

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <h1 class="mat-h1">Headline</h1>
  <ngx-masonry [options]="{itemSelector: '.masonry-item', columnWidth: '.grid-sizer', percentPosition: true }">

    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>

    <ngxMasonryItem class="masonry-item masonry-item--width2">
      <app-card id="card1" title="card 1 in full width">
        <app-card1> </app-card1>
      </app-card>
    </ngxMasonryItem>

    <ngxMasonryItem class="masonry-item">
      <app-card id="card2" title="card 2 with other width">
        <app-card2></app-card2>
      </app-card>
    </ngxMasonryItem>
</ngx-masonry>
<div>
```

Here is the code for that from my sass file:

```
.grid-sizer, 
.masonry-item {
  width: 50%;
}

.masonry-item--width2 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

The grid-container div around the masonry and headline tags does not have any custom styles.

I did not make any changes in the component.ts for masonry (only for other content related stuff, I am not allowed to share).

I tried to give all items a fix width and not do it with percent.
My result with every item in 200px was pretty unsatisfying as well:
[Example with fix width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyHvd.png)

I could not find anything about a problem like that.

If this is important: I have angular-material included in the project as well.

Help is appreciated and if anything is unclear, I am glad to share more info.

Comment: I'm having this same issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

With `@ViewChild(NgxMasonryComponent) masonry: NgxMasonryComponent;` you can access the masonry object and call the functions individually.

And using `this.masonry.reloadItems();` and `this.masonry.layout();` You can "refresh" the layout and this worked for me like a charm.

```
reloadMasonryLayout() {
    if (this.masonry !== undefined) {
      this.masonry.reloadItems();
      this.masonry.layout();
    }
  }
```

I call this function in the ngOnInit and whenever the layout changes (due to card order)

[I found this solution in a demo on github](https://github.com/wynfred/ngx-masonry-demo/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts#L17)